# Place text on the lower right of any screens

Tags: html, css

I want to place my version the bottom lower right of the screen.

```
#CSS
<style type="text/css">
    .version {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 5;
        right: 5;
        font-size: 10px;

    }
</style>
```

---

```
#HTML


<div style="position: relative;">
    <span class="version">{{ $version }}</span>
</div>
```

---

```
#RESULT
```

[image]

*What am I missing?*

Comment: How is that parent `<div>` styled? Positioning an element with `position:absolute` inside a parent element with `position:relative` will make its coordinates relative to the parent, not the viewport. `position:fixed` can work in some cases. Or simply remove the parent element. Does it get you any closer?

Comment: It’s already in the button but in relation to the body tag   You needs to expand body to maximum height by using min-height in % 90 . Try this on all wrappers until they become balanced with screen height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add px to your units.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="version">{{ $version }}</span>
</div>
.version {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    font-size: 10px;

}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
```

Also don't use inline style.

[sample](https://codepen.io/yoshinator/pen/YzzGQjj)

Answer (score 2):

As stated by @yoshinator, `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` all require units. In your case, you're probably looking to use `px`.

```
<style type="text/css">
.version {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    font-size: 10px;

}
```

Hope that helps! :)